# Some youtube videos are choppy when playing on android device

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-webview, youtube-javascript-api

I have a webview setup in an android app.  In the webview, hardware acceleration is enabled, otherwise it won't work.  The quality of all the videos I am playing is 1080p, as enabled with the YouTube api.

Now, some of the videos play back fine.  Whereas other videos playback and are really choppy.  Like it will show a few frames, get delayed and jitter a lot.  The audio in both cases is fine.

I don't know what could be causing some youtube videos to play fine and others to not.

Does anyone have any possible leads about things that could be causing this?

Comment: Are the same videos choppy all the time (and in the same places)? Or is it inconsistent, with the same video playing fine sometimes and choppy others?

Comment: @jlmcdonald yes.  The same videos are choppy consistently and in the same places.

Comment: @jlmcdonald oh man, dont leave me hanging.  It sounds like you know the answer :)

Comment: Actually, the other way around ... I've worked with someone on the converse problem where there was inconsistent choppiness. If you have a videoID of one that is playing poorly and one that plays normally, though, I'd be happy to look into it.

Comment: @jlmcdonald Thank you for the offer.  Here is one that plays normally, DiEwJTOderQ. Here MtCMtC50gwY is one that is choppy.  Did you guys figure out what was causing the inconsistent choppiness?